Problem: group of rectangles scaled, rotated and positioning in TikZ Code
I'm developing a python converter. This converter use vectorgraphis created with PowerPoint and convert this graphics into TikZ Code.
Now I created a graphic of two rectangles (size 6x4 cm) and group them. Then I rotated them by 45 degree clockwise. Then I copied it and scaled it by 50 %. The scaled group I positioned at 18 cm from the left and 5 cm from the top. In the last step i group both groups in a new group.
Then my converter has to convert this construction into TikZ code.
Target-Image created with PowerPoint:

the generated TikZ-code:
\documentclass{standalone}
        
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (0cm,0cm) rectangle (33.87cm,19.05cm);
      % group: 11 (Gruppieren 10)
      \begin{scope}
         % group: 7 (Gruppieren 6)
         \begin{scope}[scale=1.0000, rotate around={315.0000:(13.0000, 10.0500)}]
            % rectangle: 5 (Rechteck 4)
            \path [draw,line width=2.6667] (18.0000,13.0500) rectangle (22.0000,7.0500);
            % rectangle: 6 (Rechteck 5)
            \path [draw,line width=2.6667] (4.0000,13.0500) rectangle (8.0000,7.0500);
         \end{scope}
         % group: 8 (Gruppieren 7)
         \begin{scope}[scale=0.5000, shift={(18.0000cm,14.0500cm)},rotate around={315.0000:(22.5000, 12.5500)}]
            % rectangle: 9 (Rechteck 8)
            \path [draw,line width=2.6667] (18.0000,13.0500) rectangle (22.0000,7.0500);
            % rectangle: 10 (Rechteck 9)
            \path [draw,line width=2.6667] (4.0000,13.0500) rectangle (8.0000,7.0500);
         \end{scope}
      \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

and the result from the TikZ code looks like this:

You see the shrinked group is on the wrong position and i have no clue how to fix it?
I'm thankfull for any help!
PS: I updated the question and simplified the code

Welcome to TeX.SE!

do your placement coordinates take the scaling into account? e.g. if you scale=0.1 then to place something at (1,1) you'd need to use (10,10) to compensate.

@cfr thank you. Near - but still not the correct position. I also try dividing by the scaling factor. Is there any way to use a absolut position and not the shift operator? I can see the positioning point and the rotation point but i can not set this shrinked group to this exact positions.

I tried to look, but I cannot figure out from your code what it is supposed to look like. I assume it is meant to look like the powerpoint image, but what corresponds to what exactly? what are the blue shapes for? how do the red and green dots relate to the picture elements? how do the boxes relate to the ones in the target image? maybe labels would help? or colour the rectangles with fill=orange,fill opacity=0.25, say, and colour the powerpoint ones accordingly? I'm also not clear where the scaling/rotational numbers come from?

For my understanding: Why is our tikz code so complicated? If you'd do it in Tikz directly, the relevant part for the 5 objects will hardly exceed 5 lines of code or so ...

I update my questing and simplified the code to the relevant parts

Tikz is also a high-level language, take advantage of that, although I would like to know what power point output you use to do the conversion, whatever your code in tikz does not draw what you explain in text, and also the displacement is not 18 and 5 but to obtain the power point it is half of those values.
Your code uses absolute coordinates, I don't know if it is mandatory since that is how the power point exports, but you still use displacements and rotation points where you must calculate the center to do it, very complicated, in my example I defined the drawing without modifications except taking the symmetry point at the origin of the coordinates, and then invoke it doing the transformations at the end and thus I obtained a result equal to that of the power point.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
        \def\SubDraw#1#2#3#4{
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate=#2,scale=#3]
                \fill[#4](0,0) circle (0.2); %Sub-canvas anchor point
                \draw[#4](-9,-3) rectangle ++(4,6);
                \draw[#4](9,3) rectangle ++(-4,-6);
            \end{scope}
        }
        %canvas
        \def\Wcanvas{33.87}
        \def\Hcanvas{19.05}
        \useasboundingbox(0,0) rectangle (\Wcanvas,\Hcanvas);
        %the thing
        \SubDraw{13, 10.05}{0}{1}{dashed,red} % Replicate The original drawn without rotation.
        \SubDraw{13, 10.05}{-45}{1}{thick}
        \SubDraw{13+18/2, 10.05+5/2}{-45}{0.5}{}
        
        %Complements
        \draw[dashed,blue](13, 10.05) rectangle ++(18/2,5/2);
        \draw[|-|,blue] (13, 10.05)++(0,-0.3) -- ++(18/2,0) node[midway,below]{18/2};
        \draw[|-|,blue] (13, 10.05)++(-0.3,0) -- ++(0,5/2) node[midway,left]{5/2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

